# Trouble installing the Android SDK on Windows 10 through cmd

Tags: java, windows-10, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am having trouble installing the Android SDK on Windows 10. I am following a brazilian course on app development using react-native on android. This is a documentation page explaining how to create the development enviroment to do so: https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/android/windows (use google translate on the website to see the english version). However, on the part where they execute the following command :

`$ C:\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager  "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27" "build-tools;27.0.3"`

the console returns:

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli`

I have searched an entire day for a solution and discovered that, to my sorrowing dissapointment, this is a incredibly generic error when working with java in general. So I tried a plethra of things to no avail.

- Reinstalling java(64-bit version)
- Reinstalling jdk
- Checking and rechecking what could possibly be wrong with the enviroment variables(I found no problems)
- Searching through a dozen tutorials on how to install de Sdk via cmd.
- Trying to get the Sdk on my machine through Android Studio(but couldnt use any of the Sdk commands necessary for the tutorial)
- Some other stuff(I spent an entire day trying to fix this)

TLDR: I know this question has been posted in some form or regard before, I've read through all of them though, and none of them helped me.

If anyone has any idea of what I'm dealing with here, or has gone through this before, I would very much appreciate any advice that can be given. This problem has been drilling on me for a while now and I would really like to move on from it. I'm willing to provide any details on my current configuration but must of it you can find on the tutorial I linked earlier. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out there really are a billion reasons as to why this happens, and in my experience with stack, I don't think this will be answered anytime soon. So for future reference I will be giving some advice to anyone who ends up stumbling onto this problem. 
Dual-boot your machine with Linux. I know this sounds like a non solution but it really is the only feasible solution. I spent an entire week trying to solve a problem that really wasn't worth solving. There are a ton of tutorials on how to do it. It took me less than 30 minutes to set up the whole thing and voilá, everything worked as a charm. Don't waste your time trying to make stuff like this work on Windows, especially since Java is involved.

The tutorial I used: https://docs.rocketseat.dev/dual-boot-windows-linux/introducao

PS: The tutorial is in Portuguese but Google Translate works pretty much perfectly on the page, so there should be no issues.